# UIButton setImage didn't change the image of button immediately

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `setImage()` to set image on `UIButton`, but it doesn't change the image immediately. To show the image, I need to click the button or other button again. How to fix this problem?

```
block.setImage(UIImage(named: "Oimage.png"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not how you set image, but where you set image. You probably set it inside `IBAction` for button so you will have to wait then button will be pressed.

One way is to set it inside `viewDidLoad` of your view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    block.setImage(UIImage(named: "Oimage.png"), for: .normal)
}
```

... or if you're using storyboard, you can set it via storyboard. If you're creating your button programmatically, set it inside initializating `lazy` variable

Comment: How can I press the button and the button change image immediately

Comment: @IssacNgai just inside `IBAction` for your button set image. It should be immediately if your button isn't of very large size

Comment: Thank you very much, can I create a function and set image inside, then I call the function in IBAction?

Comment: @IssacNgai if you need to set image from the "beginning", set it inside `viewDidLoad`, then when you need to change image when button is pressed, set it inside `IBAction`

Answer (score 0):

You can set image in button action like this:

```
 @IBAction buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let testImage = UIImage(named:"imageName")
        block.setImage(testImage, for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change Type of your button to custom

[image]